# Same index/ID based on another column value

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access

this is my first question in this site, I want to know, if I have a table like this one in SQL

- Value
- a
- a
- a
- a
- a
- b
- b
- b
- c
- c
- a
- a
- b
- b

How can I generate a list of sequential numbers or ID's in a query in such a way that it will change according to the value column, this is what I want:

- Value;        ID
- a;          1
- a ;         1
- a  ;        1
- a  ;        1
- a  ;        1
- b  ;        2
- b  ;        2
- b  ;        2
- c  ;        3
- c  ;        3
- a  ;        4
- a  ;        4
- b  ;        5
- b  ;        5

Thanks to you all in advance for your answers.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MS Access?

Comment: Thanks for stopping by, I will use SQL server

Comment: SQL tables represent unordered sets.  There is no ordering unless you have an id or creation date that specifies the ordering.  Hence, what you are asking is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a series of queries. 
1. Start with a table containing an auto increment field and a text field, nothing else. Put no records in it. 
2. Write an aggregate query against your table that groups by your value field. 
3. Write an append query that appends record from the query in step 2 into the table from step 1. The results of that query will be what you want.

Comment: Thank you all for your answers, for what I've tested, I've used the dense Rank function, but it does not help because it groups the values and orders them, I want the records to stay as they are. If I add another column with the values 1 to 14 for each value, with this method, is there a way to achieve what I want? The main point of this is that I do not want the ABC... values to be sorted I want them to stay as they are like an Excel column.

Comment: Updated my answer, added option with a cursor. I do not know how to solve this with just a query (without using a loop)

Comment: My solution doesn't need any procedural code, just a table and 2 queries.

Answer (score 0):

Gordon Linoff is correct regarding no ordering, so it is not possible to do exactly what you ask for
But if you have an additional column to sort in SQL Server you can use DENSE_RANK to assign numbers:

```
--create table Test(col varchar(100))
--insert into Test values('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('c'),('d')

select col, DENSE_RANK() over (Order BY col)
from Test
```

It will produce

> ```
> a 1
> a 1
> a 1
> b 2
> b 2
> c 3
> d 4
> ```

Or alternatively there is always a loop or cursor loop option. This script seems to be producing your expected result:

```
/*
    drop table Test
    create table Test(ExcelRowId int not null identity primary key, data varchar(100) not null, idx int)
    insert into Test(data) values('a'),('a'),('a'),('a'),('a'),('b'),('b'),('b'),('c'),('c'),('a'),('a'),('b'),('b')
*/

declare @idx int, @prev_data varchar(100), @data varchar(100)
set @idx = 0
declare cur cursor for select Data from Test order by ExcelRowId for update of idx
open cur
fetch next from cur into @data
while @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
begin
    if @prev_data is null or @data <> @prev_data set @idx = @idx + 1
    set @prev_data = @data

    update Test set Idx = @Idx WHERE CURRENT OF cur

    fetch next from cur into @data
end
close cur
deallocate cur

select * from test
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE mytable(Id int, Value char(1))
INSERT INTO mytable
SELECT 1,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 2,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 3,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 4,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 5,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 6,'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 7,'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 8,'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 9,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 10,'a'
UNION ALL
SELECT 11,'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 12,'b'
UNION ALL
SELECT 13,'c'
UNION ALL
SELECT 14,'c';

WITH cte AS 
(SELECT 
    t1.Id
    ,t1.Value
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.Id) RowNo
FROM mytable t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN mytable t2 ON t1.Id = t2.Id - 1
WHERE 
    t2.id IS NULL
    OR t1.Value <> t2.Value)
SELECT 
mytable.Id
,mytable.Value
,MIN(cte.RowNo) RowNo
FROM
mytable
LEFT OUTER JOIN cte ON mytable.Value = cte.Value AND mytable.Id <= cte.Id
GROUP BY 
    mytable.Id
,mytable.Value
ORDER BY
mytable.id
```